# php Regular expressions basic

Tags: php, regex

I want to regex thread_id in this html code by using php

```
<a id="change_view" class="f_right" href="pm.php?view=chat&thread_id=462075438105382912">
```

I wrote this code however it return empty array to me

```
  $success = preg_match_all('/pm\.php\?view=chat&thread_id=([^"]+)/', $con, $match2);
```

is there any problem in my php code ?

Comment: There's no problem in your code. `$match2` should contain two elements.

Comment: Is it just one link or alot of links?

Comment: just one link per page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you said it is giving you an empty array. But it is not. Here is the value returned by `print_r()`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => pm.php?view=chat&thread_id=462075438105382912
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 462075438105382912
        )
)
```

But It is not returning what you want it to. The regular expression to get string that **comes after `thread_id=` and before `&` or `"`** is :

```
/(?<=thread_id=).*(?=\"|&)/
```

Working example :

```
<?php 
$con = '<a id="change_view" class="f_right" href="pm.php?view=chat&thread_id=462075438105382912">link</a>';
$match2 = Array();
preg_match_all('/(?<=thread_id=).*(?=\"|&)/', $val, $arr);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 462075438105382912
        )
)
```

Comment: is there any problem in my regex ?

Comment: @user2647541 In your regex you were making groups of both : one which is needed i.e. thread_id and other the wrapped text. Actually the regex could be made even better if you can tell about what things you are sure. As I told this regex will look for text between **thread_id** and **&** or **"**. If you are sure that it will start with `pm.php?view=chat&thread_id=` then the better regex will be `/(?<=pm.php\?view=chat&thread_id=).*(?=\"|&)/`. Or if there are other things that you are sure about, regex can be made even better.

Comment: @user2647541 There is one more thing, using *look ahead* or *look behind* cost you performance.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (preg_match('/thread_id=[0-9]*/', $line, $matches))
    $thread_id = $matches[0];
```

Comment: IMO i have problem in other part.Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

If you're only looking for the thread_id, this should do it.

```
$success = preg_match_all('/(thread_id=)([\d]+)/', $con, $match2);
```